# L2TP IPSec doesn't work from other city

Tags: networking, vpn, mikrotik-routeros, l2tp

I have a well working L2TP IPSec connection from any mobile or desktop client to my Mikrotik RB2011UiAS-2HnD-IN (RouterOS v6.30.2). It works when I connect through any mobile or stationary ISP within my city. The log of a successful connection looks approximately so:

```
ipsec, error    key length mismatched, mine:128 peer:256.
ipsec, error    authtype mismatched: my:hmac-sha1 peer:hmac-md5
l2tp, info  first L2TP UDP packet received from X.X.X.X
l2tp, ppp, info, account    MyUser logged in, 192.168.111.246
l2tp, ppp, info <l2tp-MyUser>: authenticated
l2tp, ppp, info <l2tp-MyUser>: connected
l2tp, ppp, info <l2tp-MyUser>: terminating... - peer is not responding
l2tp, ppp, info, account    MyUser logged out, 165 157 168 26 15
l2tp, ppp, info <l2tp-MyUser>: disconnected
```

Some days ago I attempted to connect from other city: through one mobile and one stationary ISP. The connection didn't succeed, and log contained only one line:

```
l2tp, info  first L2TP UDP packet received from Y.Y.Y.Y
```

or such lines:

```
ipsec, error    key length mismatched, mine:128 peer:256.
ipsec, error    authtype mismatched: my:hmac-sha1 peer:hmac-md5
l2tp, info  first L2TP UDP packet received from Y.Y.Y.Y
l2tp, info  first L2TP UDP packet received from Y.Y.Y.Y
l2tp, info  first L2TP UDP packet received from Y.Y.Y.Y
```

What is wrong? Can ISP block or corrupt L2TP IPSec connection?

P.S. There is another interesting detail:
I used to connect to Romanian PPTP VPN to bypass my home provider's web censorship and it always worked in my home city, but when I connected to the same VPN from other city (where the L2TP IPsec failed), I discovered that the site of my interest is still censored. The only explanation that comes to my mind is that provider acts like a MITM. It seems that the provider uses following tactics: tap the line, when impossible, then prevent from connecting.

Comment: ISPs can and **will** mess with your traffic. Maybe your own ISP has a policy of not allowing L2TP into his customer-facing network, but does not enforce this inside it.

Comment: @Eugen Rieck: My local provider doesn't block L2TP because I am able to connect from cellular phone through HSDPA and 3G from within my city. Is there some way to mask L2TP traffic from ISP ?